# How to add a Object to a bone

Tags: rigging

I Need to attach a Mask to a Bone 
The mask is a Object but it also has a Bone to it.
It makes me wonder if i can Merge The Head Control bone and The Mask bone
to have the mask move with the head.

Can somebody please explain how to do this?

Example picture[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wait. Nobody reply I Just answered myself. I Won't delete for if people still want to know how to do this. All i had to do was Go into the Object (The mask's) Edit mode Select the bone and delete it. Then i selected the Object and i hit the bone i wanted to connect it to, Then i hit Crtl P And hit Bone. Then it worked!